# Can I put <?php> inside <p> tag?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

It's a php file on wordpress. And I'd like to know if I can put `<?php>` inside `<p>`, `<h>` or something similar so I can add css on specific id.

For example

```
 <div class="eight columns">
            <div class="padding-right">
                <p id="address"><?php the_candidate_address(); ?></p>

            </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: sure you can. Just make sure you've PHP running and is `.php` extension. What's wrong with what you posted?

Comment: You can write PHP code everywhere you want in any .php file. Why didn't you simply test your example? You could even write `<p data-my<?php echo 'custom';?>attribute="data">`.

Comment: I'm curious though; is your site solely coded as `.html` files? Your question's pretty unclear, far as I'm concerned and is short on detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. No issues that I see. PHP code would work similarly.

Example :-

```
<p><?php echo $myName; ?></p>
```

and

```
<?php echo $myName; ?>
<p>Something else here</p>
```

both will work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
       <div class="eight columns">
                <div class="padding-right">
                    <p id="address"><?php echo "Hello"; ?></p>

                </div>
       </div>
```

Yeah, you can do that.

```
    <div class="sample">
          <p> Here goes the php code<br>
            <?php 
              date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
              echo "Today is".date("d-m-Y"); 
            ?>
         </p>
    </div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - yes. You can interleave `<?php>` tags inside any HTML tag.